# footnotesize not working with longtable and landscape

Tags: captions, fontsize, longtable, landscape

I can get `\footnotesize` to work when I'm using `landscape` & `longtable`. However, my table is `landscape` with `table-->longtable` in the environment, and when I do this I can't get the `\footnotesize` to work.

The following is my table. I can get the caption to be in `footnotesize` but not the `longtable`.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \setstretch{1}
 \usepackage{booktabs}


 \begin{document}

 \begin{landscape}
 \begin{table}[h]
  \caption{STATISTICS}

 \footnotesize

   \vspace{-2mm}

 THIS IS SOME TEXT THAT I NEED TO BE HERE.

  \vspace{-4mm}

 \end{table}
 \begin{footnotesize}
 \begin{longtable}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{c} @{}} 
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111} \\
 \midrule
 \endfirsthead
 \multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\emph{(continued)}} \\
 \toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1111111} \\
 \midrule
 \endhead
 \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
 \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{\emph{(continued)}}
 \endfoot
 \bottomrule
 \endlastfoot

 \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\underline{Unconditioning}} \\
 Constant                           & 0.073, 0.072 & 0.060, 0.068 & 0.117, 0.082           & 0.034, 0.055 & 0.059, -0.005 & -0.130, -0.025 & -0.116, -0.114 \\
                                    & (45) & (51) & (40)                                   & (28) & (32) & (43) & (16) \\
 Dummy\textsuperscript{a}           & -0.087, -0.051 & -0.219, -0.161 & -0.358, -0.333     & -1.803, -1.594 & -2.131, -0.899 & -1.030, -0.829 & -1.451, -1.193 \\
                                    & (14) & (10) & (117)                                  & (19) & (53) & (50) & (88) \\
 R-squared\textsuperscript{b}       & 0.002 & 0.003 & 0.004                                & 0.022 & 0.017 & 0.011 & 0.009 \\
 \\

 \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\underline{UNCOND}} \\
 Constant                         & 0.041, 0.042 & 0.028, 0.037 & 0.076, 0.046          & -0.007, 0.021 & 0.041, -0.012 & -0.125, -0.021 & -0.117, -0.114 \\
                                  & (31) & (32) & (23)                                  & (23) & (27) & (44) & (16) \\
 Dummy\textsuperscript{c} & 0.536, 0.465 & 0.755, 0.732 & 0.797, 0.761          & 0.910, 0.811 & 0.567, 0.395 & 0.628, 0.494 & 0.044, 0.054 \\
                                  & (245) & (287) & (403)                               & (303) & (258) & (281) & (32) \\
 Dummy                             & -0.032, -0.019 & -0.155, -0.098 & -0.197, -0.179    & -0.353, -0.282 & -1.341, -0.482 & -0.372, -0.217 & -1.451, -1.194 \\
                                   & (12) & (13) & (55)                                  & (18) & (58) & (51) & (88) \\
 R-squared                         & 0.065 & 0.119 & 0.15                                & 0.179 & 0.057 & 0.054 & 0.012 \\
 \\

 \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\underline{Unconditioning}} \\
  Constant                           & 0.040, 0.047 & 0.016, 0.034 & -0.025, -0.024   & 0.004, 0.021 & -0.007, -0.024 & -0.127, -0.024 & -0.146, -0.132 \\
                                    & (42) & (32) & (21)                              & (27) & (19) & (45) & (26) \\
 Dummy Dummy                     & 0.534, 0.472 & 0.636, 0.602 & 0.802, 0.764      & 0.706, 0.682 & 0.610, 0.401 & 0.600, 0.474 & 0.040, 0.056 \\
                                    & (241) & (280) & (404)                           & (280) & (268) & (268) & (31) \\
 Dummy\textsuperscript{d}   & 0.013, 0.013 & 0.008, 0.010 & -0.018, -0.013    & 0.011, 0.009 & 0.007, 0.001 & 0.024, 0.000 & 0.059, 0.066 \\
                                    & (18) & (29) & (19)                              & (24) & (21) & (33) & (39) \\
 Dummyyyyyyyyy*Dummy                & -0.003, -0.008 & 0.128, 0.071 & 0.020, 0.007    & 0.194, 0.100 & -0.108, -0.057 & 0.294, 0.144 & -0.155, -0.162 \\
                                    & (19) & (85) & (27)                              & (124) & (34) & (173) & (47) \\
 R-squared                          & 0.068 & 0.133 & 0.153                           & 0.206 & 0.058 & 0.062 & 0.014 \\
 \\


 \end{longtable}
 \end{footnotesize}
 \end{landscape}

 \vspace{1cm}


 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example all text is in `\footnotesize` except:

- Page number
- Caption text

The page number can be suppressed by `\pagestyle{empty}` and the caption can be
set in footnote size:

```
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
```

The document uses size option `12pt`, after compiling with

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
```

before `\begin{document}` I get two fonts only, listed at the end of the `pdflatex` run:

- `cmr10.pfb` (for the text in `\footnotesize`)
- `cmr7.pfb` (for the text in superscripts)

Font `cmr12` for `\normalsize` is not present.

Thus, why do you think that the font in the `longtable` is not in `\footnotesize`?
Or is the real question, how to get the caption in `\footnotesize`?

Comment: Nice response! Would you know how to make the table (the `longtable` part without the caption or the heading) `11pt` AND `\footnotesize`?  If I set `\documentclass[11pt]{article}` AND I use \footnotesize, my table is perfect. But I want my document to be `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` with ONLY the table as `11pt`.

Comment: If the superscripts can remain unchanged, then `\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont` would be enough.